# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate destroys missing fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Developing a node.js api. I have mongo data that shows venues. It contains an address, for example....

```
    "address": {
        "street": "123 main st",
        "city": "seomwhere",
        "state": "FL",
        "zip": "33222"
    },
       :
```

When I POST to the update endpoint and send the body like this it does update the address, but it REMOVES all the other fields that were there....

```
"address": { 
    "zip": "33222"
}
```

So, in the db, street, city, state are missing. Here's a piece of my code...

```
venue = await Venue.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
  new: true,
  runValidators: true
});
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because address contains only single key in the body (`"address": { "zip": "33222" }`) it replaces the other values inside the address object with the blank ones in the database.

So to overcome the issue you have to use `.` notation with the `address` object. Like

```
venue = await Venue.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.params.id,
  { $set: { "address.zip": "33222" },
  { new: true, runValidators: true }
)
```

But as you cannot identify which keys inside the `address` object will be updated and also for the root level

```
const object = req.body

for (var key in req.body.address) {
  object[`address.${key}`] = object.address[key]
}
delete object.address

venue = await Venue.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.params.id,
  { $set: object },
  { new: true, runValidators: true }
)
```

Comment: @SuleymanSah thanks! But, Is this really the easiest way to tell it NOT to overwrite the non-listed fields? There seems like there must be an easier way, like an option.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 as I know there is no such option unfortunately. This is just adding a few lines of code, so I think this is not a big issue. Also I have a cleaner answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting existing address fields when not specified in the request body.

You need to only update the fields in the request body:

```js
  const fields = {};

  Object.keys(req.body.address).forEach(key => {
    fields[`address.${key}`] = req.body.address[key];
  });

  const venue = await Venue.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, fields, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true
  });
```

Let's say we have this venue document:

```
{
    "_id": "5e047d4e10be4f0da4c61703",
    "name": "Venue 1",
    "address": {
        "street": "123 main st",
        "city": "seomwhere",
        "state": "FL",
        "zip": "33222"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

When you use a requset body like this:

```
{
    "address": {
        "zip": "33333"
    }
}
```

The response will be:

```
{
    "address": {
        "street": "123 main st",
        "city": "seomwhere",
        "state": "FL",
        "zip": "33333"
    },
    "_id": "5e047d4e10be4f0da4c61703",
    "name": "Venue 1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

And when we want to update like this:

```
{
    "address": {
        "state": "NY",
        "zip": "44444"
    }
}
```

The response will be:

```
{
    "address": {
        "street": "123 main st",
        "city": "seomwhere",
        "state": "NY",
        "zip": "44444"
    },
    "_id": "5e047d4e10be4f0da4c61703",
    "name": "Venue 1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: thank you! You are the best stack overflow guru! :)